# MS Project & VBA: Update Row based on PercentComplete

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm attempting to create a VBA process in MS Project that will color the row based on the "% Complete" column Value. I'm attempting to get this to update as I enter values rather than when I open, close, or run the Project. Below are two codesets.

## 1. is my attempt at the Description.

My coloring is (unfortunately) only being determined by whatever the value of c_pcStatus is during the first ELSE

```
Dim t As Task
Dim prj As Project
Dim c_pcStatus
Dim app As Application
Set app = MSProject.Application
Set prj = ActiveProject

    For Each t In prj.Tasks
        If t.PercentComplete = 100 Then
            c_pcStatus = 100
        ElseIf t.PercentComplete >= 5 And t.PercentComplete < 100 Then
            c_pcStatus = 50
        Else
            c_pcStatus = 0 'SO note:This value entry is the only one recognized
        End If

    Next t
    With app
        .ScreenUpdating = False 'allow screen refreshing

        .FilterApply "&All Tasks"
        .OutlineHideSubTasks
        .OutlineShowAllTasks
        .SelectTaskColumn Column:="PercentComplete"

        If c_pcStatus = 100 Then
            Font Color:=pjGreen, Bold:=True
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&H90EE90
        ElseIf c_pcStatus = 50 Then
            Font Color:=pjBlue, Bold:=True
        Else
            Font Color:=pjBlack, Bold:=False
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFFFFFF
        End If
    End With
```

## 2 is an VBA that will work, but runs on a task-by-task basis and generally takes forever.

```
Dim tskT As Task
For Each tskT In ActiveProject.Tasks
    Select Case tskT.PercentComplete
        Case 0 To 0
            SelectRow Row:=tskT.ID, RowRelative:=False
            Font Color:=pjBlack, Bold:=False
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFFFFFF
        Case 5 To 99
            SelectRow Row:=tskT.ID, RowRelative:=False
            Font Color:=pjBlue, Bold:=True
            'Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFFFF99
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFFFFFF 'clear
        Case 100 To 100
            SelectRow Row:=tskT.ID, RowRelative:=False
            Font Color:=pjGreen, Bold:=True
            Font32Ex CellColor:=&H90EE90
    End Select
Next tskT
```

Any help you have would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In your first attempt you only check the value of the last cell. 

Why do you not use a user defined field with a graphical output.

Comment: @INOPIAE: Thank you for responding :) This is the first VBA I've ever written. I'm surprised I was able to get it this far.If you point me in the right direction I'll give it a try